# No routes match error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Not sure why I'm getting

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"documents"}
```

in a link_to in one of my partials

relevant routes.rb

```
  resources :documents, only: [:create, :destroy, :edit, :update] do
    post 'sort' => 'documents#sort', on: :collection
  end
```

I recently just added the edit and update actions and thus my current issues
rake routes =

```
  sort_documents POST   /documents/sort(.:format)      documents#sort
       documents POST   /documents(.:format)           documents#create
   edit_document GET    /documents/:id/edit(.:format)  documents#edit
        document PUT    /documents/:id(.:format)       documents#update
                 DELETE /documents/:id(.:format)       documents#destroy
```

The partial with the problem route is just

```
 <%= document.title %>
 <%= document.position %>
 <%= link_to 'link_to_test', edit_document_path %>
 <%= link_to 'Delete', document, method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

my documents_controller.rb has
edit defined

```
def edit
    @document = current_user.documents.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you forgot to specify the object or its id in the `edit_document_path`. Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'link_to_test', edit_document_path(document) %>
```

Comment: crap, I had tried edit_document(document) lol, thanks for pointing that out